# Run minikube as a windows startup

Tags: kubernetes, cmd, deployment, devops, minikube

I have installed minikube in my windows 10. I was able to create deployment and work. But when i stop minikube everything(including deployment) is lost. How to run minikube as a service startup in windows?

Comment: What version of Minikube do you use? ``minikube stop`` should only stop running local cluster, i.e. the underlying VM or container, but user data intact is kept intact - is all deployed content lost after stopping Minikube?

Comment: Concerning running minikube on Windows start-up - isn't it a usual startup functionality for [Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-which-apps-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-9115d841-735e-488d-e749-9ba301d441e6#ID0EBD=Windows_10)? If you meant autostart of Minikube instance when host machine boots up, there is still ongoing issue to add such functionality - [Enable autostart when starting](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5301)

Comment: @anarxz I am using minikube version: v1.25.1. When i use minikube stop all the deployments is lost.

Comment: @IvigneshDavid Recently I came across such issue when all resources deployed on Minikube were lost after stopping minikube/shutting down the system - now it is fixed in the latest version, it is recommended to upgrade your installation to 1.25.2 version - link to the [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12655).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced your problem on `1.25.1` version - indeed, all resources that were deployed in the cluster are deleted on `minikube stop`.

As I already mentioned in the comments, this issue was raised [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12655). It is currently fixed in the latest release, you would need to upgrade your Minikube installation to to `1.25.2` version - basically, re-install it with newest version available [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.25.2). Confirming from my side that as soon as I've upgraded Minikube from 1.25.1 to 1.25.2 version, deployments and all other resources were present on the cluster after restarting Minikube.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It works in new version of minikube. Again thank you:)